# Understanding id returned by Facebook search

Tags: facebook-graph-api

If in a web browser I enter:

[https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=watermelo](https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=watermelon)n

the data returned begins:

{
   "data": [
      {
         "id": "100000079215099_345415575486050",
         "from": {
            "name": "Synthia Stephen",
            "id": "100000079215099"
         },

My question relates to the id field. The value returned contains two numbers separated by an underscore character.

1) I believe the first number (100000079215099) is the id of a facebook user, is this always the case?

2) What does the second number (345415575486050) represent?

3) Once I have the full id (100000079215099_345415575486050) is it possible to use this id in another Facebook Graph API to retrieve the data associated with this id? If so, what would that url look like?

Comment: I would suggest playing around with this via the Graph API Explorer.  I learned a lot by playing around with all sorts of Graph API Posts, Deletes, and Gets there.

Answer (score 2):

On facebook Evry user has ID and every event associated with it may be a status or photo also has an ID.

**100000079215099_345415575486050**

The first part of it represents the user id and second part represents the Event(Activity like a status or post) Id.

To Understand Better go to https://developers.facebook.com/graph-academy
 Answers to your question:

1) First one will always be user id.

2) Mentioned above this is specific event related id. (Status or pic)

3) Yes, you can use this id everywhere in other APIs.

Answer (score 0):

1) Yes the first number is the ID.
2) I'm not sure, I think it may be something to track where the view came from and who the viewer is. Perhaps an access token.
3) https://graph.facebook.com/100000079215099

https://graph.facebook.com/100000079215099_49874987249823749283

```
{
   "error": {  
      "message": "(#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: 100000079215099_49874987249823749283",  
      "type": "OAuthException"  
   }  
}
```

https://graph.facebook.com/100000079215099_345415575486052

```
false
```

https://graph.facebook.com/100000079215099
returns her data, but I'm omitting it